# Add sorting by stock quantity in WooCommerce products sort by

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I have added the following code to my theme `functions.php`.

The "Availability" sort option does show up but when I select it, it is sorted by Title, not stock quantity.

I also tried using `stock_quantity` as a `meta_key` (even though it's not a meta) and that didn't work either.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
$orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'availability' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'stock_quantity';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['availability'] = 'Availability';
    return $sortby;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last update: 02/22 - Tested in WordPress 5.9.1 & WooCommerce 6.1.1

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

---

Use `['meta_key'] = '_stock'` & `['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'` instead

So you get:

```php
// Ordering products based on the selected values
function filter_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args, $orderby, $order ) {    
    switch( $orderby ) {
        case 'availability':
            $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
            $args['order']    = 'DESC';
            $args['meta_key'] = '_stock';
            break;
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'filter_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 10, 3 );

// Orderby setting
function filter_orderby( $orderby ) {
    $orderby['availability'] = __( 'Availability', 'woocommerce' );
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'filter_orderby', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'filter_orderby', 10, 1 );

// Optional: use for debug purposes (display stock quantity) 
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    global $product;
    echo '<div style="color: red !important; font-size: 20px !important;">' . wc_get_stock_html( $product ) . '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 9, 0 );
```