# Woocommerce Custom Sorting Showing Different Results on Refresh

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a custom orderby for woocommerce however everytime I refresh it's bringing back different results! Not sure why the values stored in the DB are 1,2,3,4,5 etc all the way to 418. I am displaying the products on the page using the foreach method not WP_Query.

```
function skyverge_add_postmeta_ordering_args( $sort_args ) {
    
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
    $sort_args['order']    = 'asc';
    $sort_args['meta_key'] = 'lot_number';
    return $sort_args;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'skyverge_add_postmeta_ordering_args' );


// Add these new sorting arguments to the sortby options on the frontend
function skyverge_add_new_postmeta_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['lot_number'] = __( 'Sort by Lot Number', 'woocommerce' );
    return $sortby;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'skyverge_add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'skyverge_add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
```

I've also tried:

```
function skyverge_add_postmeta_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( $orderby_value == 'lot_number' ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = 'lot_number';
    } return $args;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'skyverge_add_postmeta_ordering_args', 10, 1 );   

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['lot_number'] = 'Sort By Lot Number';
    return $sortby;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 10, 1 );
```

Code used to display the products:

```
function gw_new_auctions_fun( $atts ) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'per_page'  => 25,
        'orderby' => 'lot_number',
        'order' => 'desc'
    ), $atts));

    if(!function_exists('wc_get_products')) {return;}

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
    $ordering = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args();
    $ordering['orderby'] = array_shift(explode(' ', $ordering['orderby']));
    $ordering['orderby'] = stristr($ordering['orderby'], 'price') ? 'meta_value_num' : $ordering['orderby'];
    $products_per_page = apply_filters('loop_shop_per_page', $per_page);

    $products_ids = wc_get_products(array(
        'status' => 'publish',
        'type' => 'auction',
        'limit' => 25,
        'page' => $paged,
        'paginate' => true,
        'order' => $ordering['order'],
        'orderby' => $ordering['orderby'],
        'return' => 'ids',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'woo_ua_auction_closed',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ));

    wc_set_loop_prop('current_page', $paged);
    wc_set_loop_prop('is_paginated', wc_string_to_bool(true));
    wc_set_loop_prop('page_template', get_page_template_slug());
    wc_set_loop_prop('per_page', $products_per_page);
    wc_set_loop_prop('total', $products_ids->total);
    wc_set_loop_prop('total_pages', $products_ids->max_num_pages);

    ob_start();
    if($products_ids) : do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop')?>
        <div class="filters">
            <?php get_template_part('inc/partials/breadcrumbs'); ?>
            <div class="page-number"><p>Page <?php if ($paged == 0): $paged = 1; endif; echo $paged;?> of <?php echo wc_get_loop_prop( 'total_pages' );?></p></div>
            <div class="total-items"><p><?php echo wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' );?> Items</p></div>
            <div class="dropdown-filter"><p>Sort By: </p><?php woocommerce_catalog_ordering();?></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="products">
            <?php do_action('woocommerce_product_loop_start');
                foreach($products_ids->products as $featured_product) {
                    $post_object = get_post($featured_product);
                    setup_postdata($GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object);
                    wc_get_template_part('content', 'product-archive');
                }
            do_action('woocommerce_product_loop_end') ?>
        </ul>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
    else :
        wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' );
    endif; wp_reset_postdata();
    
    return '<div class="woocommerce woocommerce-auction">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: For the first - check this key 'lot_number' and 'lotnumber', maybe there is an error http://prntscr.com/vg7wze And maybe can you provide site url?

Comment: @AlexanderZ no luck and here: ```bit.ly/3kihMvw```

Comment: You're using `$orderby_value = isset(..` but then you don't use it anymore. Try it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62353255/11987538), it is a different meta_key, but it comes down to the same thing

Comment: @7uc1f3r that's made it worse

Comment: Interesting, do you know why it might then bring back a different order of products very refresh? I will add my shortcode code that pulls in the filter/products.

Comment: A conflict with another code, a plugin, your theme .. can be due to several things 
and therefore cannot be answered in general. These kinds of issues should be resolved by debugging, since it works by default (WooCommerce 4.6.2) without problems.

Comment: @7uc1f3r added shortcode code for u to check if possible?