# Woocommerce default catalog sorting by numeric meta field - why doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I need to sort products on the shop page by numeric meta field _sort_field from low to high values and make this sorting default.

```
//adding new switch-case option
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'wh_catalog_ordering_args');
function wh_catalog_ordering_args($args) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($_GET['orderby'])) {
        switch ($_GET['orderby']) {            
            case 'sort_field' :
                $args['order'] = 'ASC';
                $args['meta_key'] = '_sort_field';
                $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
                break;
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

//To add to Dashboard > WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'wh_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'wh_catalog_orderby');
function wh_catalog_orderby($sortby) {
    $sortby['sort_field'] = 'Sort by Power';   
    return $sortby;
}

//to make this sorting default
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
                $args['order'] = 'ASC';
                $args['meta_key'] = '_sort_field';
                $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
return $args;
}
```

The sorting is default, but the order itself is wrong. The field is numeric, but the order of products is still random. Products woth his field value 15 are earlier then products with value 12 or 7 or 6. Where I made a mistake in the code?

Comment: Why are you using the same hook (`woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args`) twice? 
the code you use with the first hook should suffice. See this similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62353255/11987538)