# Sort WooCommerce store products based on inventory

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use this code to sort the inventory of a WordPress store. This code has two problems

1. Instead of calculating the product inventory numerically, it puts it into an array and therefore cannot properly sort the products based on the inventory.

2. If the code is active, it will not show the new added products.

```
add_action('init', function() {
    if( isset($_GET['update_products_arv']) ) {
        $products = wc_get_products( [ 'limit' => 500,'offset' => 200] );
        foreach( $products as $product ){
            $total_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity() ? : 0;
            if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
                $variations = $product->get_children();
                if( !$variations ) continue;
                foreach ($variations as $variation_id) {
                    $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
                    $total_stock += $variation->get_stock_quantity() ? : 0;
                }
            }
            update_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'nsaeidi_stock', $total_stock);
        }
    }
});

add_action('woocommerce_product_query', function($q) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        $q->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $q->set('meta_key', 'nsaeidi_stock');
        $q->set('order', 'DESC');
    }
});
```

Please tell me how to modify the code?

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353002/add-sorting-by-stock-quantity-in-woocommerce-products-sort-by